# OverlapCircleAll is not picking up other objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overlap

I am trying to get all objects within a distance of the current object. the `maxShootDistance` is set to 3, and when an object that is part of the `ShootAt` layer gets near/in the circle, it is never picked up, and my debug outputs `0`. Why isn't it picking up the other object?

```
public class QuckShot : Gun {

    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(shoot());
    }

    IEnumerator shoot(){
        while(true){
            Collider2D[] hitColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, maxShootDistance, LayerMask.NameToLayer("ShootAt"));
            Debug.Log(hitColliders.Length); // This is always returning zero
            /*
             * Snipped other bits of code
             */
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(shootSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the properties that are assigned to the object that should have been picked up:

[image: Female Properties]

Why isn't my code picking up the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This call:

```
LayerMask.NameToLayer("ShootAt")
```

[NameToLayer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html) returns a layer index (ie: 7), but [OverlapCircleAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html) expects a bitwise layer *mask* (ie: 7th bit enabled).

In some circumstances, this sort of thing may appear to work, if the layer index happens to have a bit or two in common with the desired layer mask. Either way, it'll get unintuitive and mixed results at best.

You can construct a layer mask using the [bitwise left shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8xftzc7e.aspx):

```
1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("ShootAt");
```

(You can add additional layers using bitwise OR.)